# Cypher Relationship Type returning no results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm getting some unexpected results when trying to define the type of a relationship in a Cypher Query.      My model consists of Action nodes which are related to an ActionType node via an :OCCURRENCE_OF relationship.  Here is a sample create query:

```
START m=node(100), p=node(200)
CREATE (a:Action {created:1415534077})-[:OCCURRENCE_OF]->(m),
       (a)-[:PERFORMED_BY]->(p)
```

If I run a query on these results I see that there are relationships in the database with the type I've defined.

```
$ match (a)-[r]->(m) return count(a), type(r);
+-----------------------------+
| count(a) | type(r)          |
+-----------------------------+
| 2412     | "OCCURENCE_OF"   |
+-----------------------------+
```

However, if I try to run a cypher query using the relationship name - the query returns 0 results despite being able to see these if I don't explicitly state the relationship type.

```
$ MATCH (m:ActionType)<-[r]-(a:Action) return distinct type( r) ,min(a.created), max(a.created);
+--------------------------------------------------+
| type( r)       | min(a.created) | max(a.created) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| "OCCURENCE_OF" | 1413718386     | 1416224203     |
+--------------------------------------------------+


$ match (a)-[:OCCURRENCE_OF]->(m) return count(a);
+----------+
| count(a) |
+----------+
| 0        |
+----------+
```

I've tried wrapping the relationship in quotes (', ’, ") but I'm still getting no results.  What am I missing?!

Comment: Can you check the spelling of the relation? The create has OCCURRENCE_OF, but type(r) in your subsequent queries show "OCCURENCE_OF"  and finally your last match with 0 results refers to OCCURRENCE_OF

Comment: Here's another thing that doesn't make sense.  When you run `match (a)-[r]->(m) return count(a), type(r);` why does that **only** return one relationship type, when in the query above you created a `:PERFORMED_BY` relationship?   Also, you might want to consider using MATCH instead of START since I hear START may end up deprecated.   Also, you should try this on a clean test database.  Some of your results suggest that the queries you're running are happening when the DB is in a different state, not just these running sequentially.

Comment: @Luanne Does the type of the relationship need to be cast so it isn't applied as a string? With quotes maybe?  I wasn't aware a relationship type could be anything other than a string.

@FrobberOfBits I've removed the `:PERFORMED_BY` relationships for berevity

Comment: No casting required for the relation type. [:OCCURRENCE_OF] is correct. Please re-try on a clean graph and update your post with the fresh sequence and results

Comment: I think it is misspelling as Luanne said.

Comment: I created the relationships with Cypher using Everyman's Neo4j PHP package - would this be a possible bug where it casts the relationship type as a string?  The only difference between the two is the quotes around type(r) in the results.